# Should coverage.py present unit test code's coverage too?

Tags: python, python-3.x, code-coverage, coverage.py

I have a small Python 3 project that I intend to keep as a reusable library. Let's call it utils_common. The coverage report from coverage.py includes some coverage for actual unit tests code along "production" code and I think I'm doing something wrong here.

The directory structure is:

```
utils_common_prj             (root project directory)
    utils_common             (directory, actual code package)
        __init__.py          (empty file)
        data_convert.py      (some module with a class with static methods)
        ...                  (other modules with code)
    tests                    (directory, test code package)
        __init__.py.         (empty file)
        test_data_convert.py (unit test class, testing class DataConvert)
        ...                  (other unit tests)
    setup.py                 (file, used to create the .tar.gz dist package)
    .pylintrc
    .gitignore
```

So I run unit tests with code coverage using coverage.py like so: having current directory utils_common_prj I run:

```
coverage run --source=. --omit=setup.py -m unittest discover
```

Followed by

```
coverage report
```

What I get is:

```
Name                                      Stmts   Miss  Cover
-------------------------------------------------------------
utils_common/__init__.py                      0      0   100%
utils_common/data_convert.py                 10      0   100%
...
tests/__init__.py                             0      0   100%
tests/test_data_convert.py                   39      0   100%
...
-------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                       222      0   100%
```

I am getting statement count and percentage from test code along with actual code and I don't think this is desirable.

Coming from a .NET and Java background this seems like an error. Is it an error? If so, how should I fix it?

Comment: Try [omitting the test files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8392485/10077) from coverage.

Comment: @FredLarson: I tried to make the omit option like so: --omit=setup.py,tests/* but it doesn't accept the star and without the star it doesn't change anything... Any hints for the omit syntax?

Comment: I don't have anything other than what I linked.

Comment: `coverage run --source=. --omit=setup.py,*test* -m unittest discover` leads to `zsh: no matches found: --omit=setup.py,*test*`.

However, placing the omit value in quotes does the trick! Like so:
`coverage run --source=. --omit='setup.py,*test*' -m unittest discover`

It works now! Thanks!

Comment: @FredLarson : You can put this above information as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using omit flag in Python coverage.py API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392485/using-omit-flag-in-python-coverage-py-api)

Comment: slightly.. I got a hint from there on how to change the command line (the recommandation there is to use a .coveragerc file) and also hints that you would not want the test code measured too although not explicitly... so partially. I, personally, wouldn't consider this question (and answers to it) as duplicate to the one linked..